# What war is referred to in the TV Show 'Gotham?'

Tags: gotham

Gotham is referred to as a timeless series, so they can't be referring to a specific war we know of. Such examples of references to the war is where Captain Barnes talks about the war he was in when explaining to Gordon about 'the line'.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68220/31029

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you just answered your own question: it can't be in reference to a particular war due to the timeless nature of the series, so it instead refers to some unspecified past war?

Given the technological time frame of Gotham, the story has to have happened in the last 50-60 years in the US; and there has been no shortage of past wars in this timeframe. Even if you expand it to 100 years, you'll still find that there will always have been a recent past war.

Comment: I said a 'war we know of.' By this I meant a war in real life. It could be fictional. What I was wondering is if there is any actual specification to this war either in this show or any other DC medium such as the comics

Comment: @yolo: Even then, in order to be timeless, you can't delve into specifics. Wars tend to showcase top technology which can very quickly date the war and thus no longer make it timeless. The only way to avoid that is to avoid any specifics about the war itself and only focus on the aftermath of it. I'm not saying it can't be done but it'd take some effort to pull off without breaking the timeless constraint, and the war is simply not in focus enough for the effort to matter.

Comment: Ah yes- but by timeless, in context of what BC referenced in the OP's comments was that it isn't a time in our history but Gotham has its own time- fixed but not relevant to us. Therefore it can have RPGs *and* old fashioned radio systems. So I think gotham has time but only relative to the events within it. For example batman is around a decade after gotham and I presume the war is around a decade before gotham